# Reduce array of object to totals by property object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for a smart ES6 way to reduce array of objects into totals-by-property-object.

for a sample data:

```
const src = [{mon:1,tue:0,wed:3,thu:5,fri:7,sat:0,sun:4}, {mon:5,tue:3,wed:2,thu:0,fri:1,sat:0,sun:6}];
```

following code:

```
const res = src.reduce((totals,item) => Object.keys(item).forEach(weekday => totals[weekday] += item[weekday]),{})
```

throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mon' of undefined

even if `reduce` is initialized with `{mon:0, tue:0 ...}` instead of `{}`.

Is there a non-for-loop solution?

p.s. expected output is an object where each property is a sum of array objects by that property, e.g. `{mon:6, tue:3, wed:5, thu:5, fri:8, sat:0, sun:10}` in my case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return `totals` after you modify it:

```js
const src = [{mon:1,tue:0,wed:3,thu:5,fri:7,sat:0,sun:4}, {mon:5,tue:3,wed:2,thu:0,fri:1,sat:0,sun:6}];

const res = src.reduce((totals, item) => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(weekday => totals[weekday] = (totals[weekday] || 0) + item[weekday]);
  
  return totals;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that close. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return `totals` as accumulator for `reduce`.

If you have allways all days in the objects and you don't mind to mutate the first object, you could work without a start object.

```js
const
    src = [{ mon: 1, tue: 0, wed: 3, thu: 5, fri: 7, sat: 0, sun: 4 }, { mon: 5, tue: 3, wed: 2, thu: 0, fri: 1, sat: 0, sun: 6 }],
    res = src.reduce((totals, item) => 
        (Object.keys(item).forEach(d => totals[d] += item[d]), totals));

console.log(res);
```